# UILabel does not change

Tags: ios5, uiview, uilabel, xcode4.3

```
@interface TopBarController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate> {

UILabel *coinWatch;   }
@property (nonatomic,retain) UILabel *coinWatch;






- (UIView *)coinsLabel {
UIView *coinsLabelView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(36, 17, 100, 15)];
//if (coinsLabelView == nil) {
    coinWatch = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3, 0, 100, 15)];
    coinWatch.font = [self coinsFont];
    coinWatch.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.83 blue:0.16 alpha:1];
    coinWatch.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",  data.getCoins];
    NSLog(@"label %d",data.getCoins);
    coinWatch.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
//}

[coinsLabelView addSubview:coinWatch];
return coinsLabelView;
```

}

```
- (void) setCoin {

[coinWatch performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setText:) withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",  data.getCoins] waitUntilDone:NO];
NSLog(@"coin %d",data.getCoins);
NSLog(@"Really updating");
```

}

I'm new to xcode but this is my simple code for updating coinWatch(UILabel). the label initially has 0 but when I added the coin using other functions(not shown in here), the NSLog prints the correct amount but does not update...When ever I call for setCoin, it does not update the coinWatch text in the view. Please help this miserable newbie!!!

Comment: in which class setCoin method is implemented...? is it in TopBarController.m file?

Comment: you have to implement set coin method into TopBarController.m where is coinWatch label is implemented

Comment: give us your full code your above code is incomplete because i can not predict in which class each method is implemented format your code with file name

Comment: how you call -(void)setCoin method ?